# Is the following inequality true? $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)}\leq \|u\|_{H_0^2(U)}$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Is the following inequality true? $$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)}\leq \|u\|_{H_0^2(U)}$$

I see that:
$$\|\Delta u \|_{L^2(U)}=\|\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_ix_i}\|_{L^2(U)}$$
and $$\|u\|_{H_0^2(U)}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2} \|D^\alpha u\|^2_{L^2(U)}\right)^{\frac12}$$

Where this contains each $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=2$, and hence

$$\sqrt{\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)}}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\| u_{x_ix_i}\|_{L^2(U)}}\leq \|u\|_{H_0^2(U)}$$

But I am not sure how to proceed, if it is even true.

Comment: If you chuck in a $\sqrt n$ on the RHS then this is true. Try first proving the pointwise inequality $|\Delta u|^2 \le n \sum_{i,j} |u_{x_i x_j}|^2$. If it helps, this is a special case of the inequality $(\mathrm{tr} M)^2 \le n\; \mathrm{tr}(M^T M)$ for $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis can you please check my self-answer?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I think I have solved it with your suggestion

Comment: looks good if you're willing to take the matrix inequality as given.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Hessian matrix $M=D^2u$.

We have from linear algebra, the following:
$$(\text{tr}(M))^2\leq n \text{tr}(MM^T)$$

So we we find that:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_ix_i}\right)^2 \leq n \sum_{i,j=1}^n u_{x_ix_j}u_{x_ix_j}$$
$$\implies |\Delta u|^2\leq n \left|\sum_{i,j=1}^n u_{x_ix_j}u_{x_ix_j}\right|$$

So then:
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)}^2 =\int_U |\Delta u|^2 dx \leq \int_U n \sum_{i,j=1}^n |u_{x_ix_j}|^2 dx=n\sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_U |u_{x_ix_j}|^2 dx=n\sum_{i,j=1}^n \|u_{x_ix_j}\|_{L^2(U)}^2$$$$=n\sum_{|\alpha|=2} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^2(U)}^2 \leq n\|u\|_{H^2_0(U)}^2$$

So that we have found:
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(U)} \leq \sqrt{n}\|u\|_{H^2_0(U)}$$